# jQuery: catch click event from usercontrol

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got UserControl with button. I'm trying to catch click event of this button using jQuery.
My code in ascx:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myjQueryCode.js"></script>

<button id="test-button">Test</button>
```

Code in myjQueryCode.js.

I've tried this:

```
$('#test-button').bind('click', function() {
    alert("123");
});
```

and this:

```
$("[id$=test-button]")
    .button()
    .click(function() {
        alert("123");
});
```

and this:

```
$('#test-button')
    .button()
    .click(function() {
        alert("123");
});
```

Nothing is work.

Comment: Could you show us the html generated? and in which part of your code your adding the javascript. Second if your using chrome open the developer tools with f12 and check for errors

Comment: The same code in aspx page works correct.

Comment: The generated html is exactly the same as code above in ascx file. A add only a link on js file with my javascript code. And I want this code intercepted button click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just be:

```
$('#test-button').click(function () {
    console.log('Click activated.');
});
```

Make sure that the code can actually execute.  For example, wrap the statement in an executed function like so:

```
(function () {
    // Write code here
}());
```

Or execute once the document is ready, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Write code here
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { alert('1') }); Do nothing too. Tell me please what does it mean.

Comment: Your Javascript code isn't executing. Perhaps you didn't include the <script> tag properly in your HTML.

Comment: The path in links to js files is correct. Could be another reason?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to put your code iside the `$(document).ready()`?
Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#test-button').bind('click', function() {
        alert("123");
    });

});
```

Comment: Maybe you are creating the button dynamically?
try to use `.live()` instead of `.bind()`...

Comment: .live() didn't work too. Can be the difference between aspx and ascx pages? In aspx this code works well.

Comment: Can you go to 'View Source' of the page and locate the button? check if the id is still `test-button` or something like `ctl00_test-button`

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { alert('1') }); Do nothing too. Tell me please what does it mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place your script code after your html code - maybe this will help...

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code is being executed before the element exists (because the `<script>` tag is before the HTML for your button), so you'll need to wrap it in a DOM ready event handler. Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test-button').bind('click', function() {
        alert("123");
    });
});
```

For further information, look at the API documentation for the [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function and the [Getting Started with jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach using jQuery, and not referencing .button() works in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cd5Qj/

So it's likely that either you've got the wrong path to the jQuery library in your script tag, or you're not including the code inside a jQuery block like:

```
$(function(){
  ... //code here
});
```

...or there's some conflict we can't examine because there's more code you haven't displayed here.